# Converting a whole database from one charset / collation to utf8 / utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, collation

I know there are already a lot of similar questions to this, many even the same; I have spent the last 45 mins looking around at possible solutions, but haven't none of the solutions I have found really answer all my questions / concerns.

I have this possible solution via the CLI:

```
mysql --user=username --password=your_pass --database=dbname -B -N -e
"SHOW TABLES"  | awk '{print "ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;"}' | mysql --user=username --password=your_pass 
--database=dbname &
```

Then we have one from [this page](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/420-Converting-a-MySQL-database-from-latin1-to-utf8), which basically does this:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u root --password='password' db_name | sed
-e 's/CHARSET\=latin1/CHARSET\=utf8\ COLLATE\=utf8_unicode_ci/g' | iconv -f
latin1 -t utf8 | mysql -u root --password='password' db_name
```

However this one seems like you have to do it a table at a time.

Then there is [this one](http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/17/converting-character-sets/), this sounded goo apart from the fact it only does the character set and *not* the collation.

So basically I'm looking for a solution similar to the last one that will convert the whole database's charset *and* collation and is a well done solution such as to convert the table indexes including fulltext keys correctly as pointed out in the last article.

I'm not sure how good the first two solutions are when it comes to converting the indexes correctly either.

So with so many solutions, I am just looking for one that will convert things correctly including tables, columns & indexes.